# Can we improve on the inequality $\sigma(N)\varphi(N) < N^2$ for composite integers $N > 1$?

Tags: proof-verification, inequality, totient-function, upper-lower-bounds, divisor-sum

It is [known](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3388291) that there is no room for improvement to the inequality $\sigma(p)\varphi(p) < p^2$ for primes $p$, since the usual formulae for the sum of divisors and Euler totient functions give
$$\sigma(p) = p + 1$$
$$\varphi(p) = p - 1.$$

Here is my question:

> Can we improve on the inequality $\sigma(N)\varphi(N) < N^2$ for *composite* integers $N > 1$?

**MY ATTEMPT**

Consider the case $N = q^k$ a prime power.

Then we have
$$\sigma(N) = \sigma(q^k) = \frac{q^{k+1} - 1}{q - 1}$$
and
$$\varphi(N) = \varphi(q^k) = q^{k-1} (q - 1)$$
so that we obtain
$$\sigma(N)\varphi(N)=\sigma(q^k)\varphi(q^k)=\bigg(\frac{q^{k+1} - 1}{q - 1}\bigg)\cdot\bigg(q^{k-1} (q - 1)\bigg)=q^{2k} - q^{k-1}.$$

Since both $\sigma$ and $\varphi$ are multiplicative, this means that if we have the canonical prime factorization
$$\displaystyle\prod_{i=1}^{w}{{p_i}^{\alpha_i}}$$
for $N$, then we have the following exact expression for $\sigma(N)\varphi(N)$:
$$\displaystyle\prod_{i=1}^{w}{\bigg({p_i}^{2\alpha_i} - {p_i}^{\alpha_i - 1}\bigg)},$$
where $w = \omega(N)$ is the number of distinct prime factors of $N$.

Consequently, it *may* be possible to tweak the upper bound to get a minor(?) or substantial(?) improvement, but I am not seeing it.

**UPDATE (1 NOV 2019 - 09:24 AM Manila time)**

Basically, I want an upper bound for $\sigma(N)\varphi(N)$, in terms of $N$, that is sharper than $N^2$.

Comment: i dont understand what you want. it seems like you've done the relevant work

Comment: Thank you for your feedback, @mathworker21.  Basically, I want an upper bound for $\sigma(N)\varphi(N)$ that is sharper than $N^2$.

Comment: For $$n=9972337=197\cdot 223\cdot 227$$ we have $$\frac{\varphi(n)\cdot \sigma(n)}{n^2}=0.9999347\cdots$$ so I am sceptical.

Comment: Even more spectacular is this number having $3$ distinct prime factors : 6110020423763  0.99999999009339009925990593396869620209

Comment: Thank you for your time and attention, @Peter.  Please write out your last two comments as an actual answer to this question, so that I may be able to upvote and accept.  =)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that also for composite $n$ (not even semiprime), the fraction $$\frac{\varphi(n)\sigma(n)}{n^2}$$ can get arbitary close to $\ 1\ $, which would mean that $\ n^2\ $ cannot significantly be improved.

A particular striking number is

$$6110020423763=14173\cdot 17419\cdot 24749$$ giving $$0.99999999009339\cdots $$

So, $\ n^2\ $ seems to be sharp also for composite numbers.

Comment: If we set $$\ n=pqr\ $$ with distinct primes $\ p,q,r\ $, then we have $$\frac{\varphi(n)\cdot \sigma(n)}{n^2}=\frac{(p-1)(q-1)(r-1)(p+1)(q+1)(r+1)}{p^2q^2r^2}=(1-\frac{1}{p})(1+\frac{1}{p})(1-\frac{1}{q})(1+\frac{1}{q})(1-\frac{1}{r})(1+\frac{1}{r})$$ Hence if the smallest prime factor tends to $\ \infty\ $, the value tends to $\ 1\ $

Comment: This of course also holds for more than $\ 3\ $ distinct prime factors.

Comment: Adding the content of these Comments to your existing Answer would significantly improve it (in my opinion).